# How to change supported account types using power shell

Tags: azure, powershell

I have created application in AAD using following command

```
New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "testApp" -HomePage "http://www.microsoft.com" -IdentifierUris "http://NewApplicationTest"
```

This creates application successfully in AAD.
Now i want to update the "Supported account types". I have tried the below code.

```
Update-AzureRmADApplication -ObjectId <ObjectID> -AvailableToOtherTenants $true
```

I got an error as

**Update-AzureRmADApplication : Updates to converged applications are not allowed in this version.
At line:1 char:1**

can any one have idea where the mistake is.
Any help can be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

After you've created the app registration, try the following commands instead:

```
Get-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "testApp" | Set-AzureRmADApplication -AvailableToOtherTenants $true
```

Or you could simply make it available to other tenants in one line:

```
New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "testApp" -HomePage "http://www.microsoft.com" -IdentifierUris "http://NewApplicationTest" -AvailableToOtherTenants $true
```

You should also check which version of the AzureAD PowerShell module you're using.  Converged accounts were introduced with AAD V2 and so if you're using the V1 module it may be trying to use the V1 API which would fail.  You can get the version like this:

```
Get-Module -Name AzureAD
```

If it says Version 1.X then update it like so:

```
Update-Module -Name AzureAD
```

Comment: Edit:  Changed Update-AzureRmADApplication to Set-AzureRmADApplication.  The Update-AzureRmADApplication seems to have been deprecated in V2.

Comment: Thank for reply @Jamiei tried the first one but it says "Update-AzureRmADApplication : Host name in property identifierUris is not on any verified domain of the company or its subdomain."

Comment: I am trying this in Azure Portal directly.

Comment: @venkatesh You need to use the **Set**-AzureRmADApplication cmdlet and you may wish to use `-IdentifierUris "http[colon]//xyz.com"` where xyz.com is a valid domain you own and have verified in Azure, or the yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com domain provided out of the box.